# 3D Extruded LINESTRING exports invalid geoJSON

Tags: postgis, polygon, geojson, cesium

I am using postGIS and want to create cube from a 2D linestring. I use the `ST_Extrude` option to create the 3D polygons and combines these with the `ST_AsGeoJSON` operator to export my individual polygons, but it seems that when I run these through a validator like [geojson.io](https://geojson.io) that I keep getting errors regarding some of the polygons:
"Polygons and MultiPolygons should follow the right-hand rule".

I've also tried to force the RHR using the `ST_ForcePolygonCCW` operator, as shown in my example query below, but that does not seem to fix anything, same error.

```
With exampleRegion (geom) as (select ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING (0 0 0, 0 1 0, 1 1 0, 1 0 0, 0 0 0)'))
SELECT (a.p_geom).path[1] As path, ST_AsGEOJSON(ST_ForcePolygonCCW((a.p_geom).geom)) As geom_ewkt
FROM (SELECT st_dump(st_extrude(ST_MakePolygon(geom), 0, 0, 3)) AS p_geom FROM exampleRegion) AS a
```

The following table is the result of the query specified in my post:

```
1 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[0,0,0],[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]]}" 
2 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[0,0,3],[1,0,3],[1,1,3],[0,1,3],[0,0,3]]]}" 
3 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[0,0,0],[0,0,3],[0,1,3],[0,1,0],[0,0,0]]]}" 
4 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[0,1,0],[0,1,3],[1,1,3],[1,1,0],[0,1,0]]]}" 
5 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[1,1,0],[1,1,3],[1,0,3],[1,0,0],[1,1,0]]]}" 
6 "{""type"":""Polygon"",""coordinates"":[[[1,0,0],[1,0,3],[0,0,3],[0,0,0],[1,0,0]]]}"
```

Is there some other way to create valid geoJSON format to describe my 3D object?

Comment: Could you add an example about the generated GeoJSON?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GeoJSON format https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7946 is made for 2D geometries or optionally 25D geometries with height as a third element. The format itself and tools which are built around it do not deal with true 3D geometries.

As an example, take just one extruded vertical face as a polygon.

As WKT:

```
POLYGON Z ((0 1 0,0 1 3,1 1 3,1 1 0,0 1 0))
```

As GeoJSON:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "name": "testwkt",
    "features": [{
        "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {},
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Polygon",
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    [0, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 3],
                    [1, 1, 3],
                    [1, 1, 0],
                    [0, 1, 0]
                ]
            ]
        }
    }]
}
```

In 2D space the polygon has only two distinct points: `0,1` and `1,1`. That makes the polygon invalid. It is also invalid for PostGIS:

```
SELECT ST_IsValidReason(
ST_GeomFromText(
'POLYGON Z ((0 1 0,0 1 3,1 1 3,1 1 0,0 1 0))'
))

Result:
"Too few points in geometry component[0 1 0]"
```

You must use some other format than GeoJSON for 3D geometries.